# how to send date through URL in ajax

Tags: java, ajax, model-view-controller

Hi i have to append Date to a URL, maintaining its Datatype as Date and not as String 
When in append Date to URL as "?date=" + $(target).val();
i fetch it through @RequestParameter in my Controller
But the problem here lies that i cant access it as Date but as String.
If i access it as Date it does not gives an error but changes the format of the Date from 2017-05-12 00:00:00 to something like Fri MAY 12 00:00:00 IST 2017.
So i need to send data as date through AJAX so when i access in my Controller i can maintain its format

As far as i know when i fetch the data as Date it gives me internal representation of Date because there is internal conversion of String to Date
Thus i need to know how i can send date through URL in AJAX

Comment: a Date how no intrinsic formatting.  try sending it as a long `getTime()`

Comment: I URL every data will be just string, You can get that string and if it is a valid date just convert it to the date format you want.

Comment: yes i can format the Date on receiving but then it messes with my i18n feature

Comment: i need a way in which i can maintain the format of date through out the process from AJAX to controller

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass types via GET URL parameters.
You need to convert the type on your java code.

For example:

```
new SimpleDateFormat( "MM/dd/yyyy H:m:s" ).parse( @RequestParam( "date" ) )
```

It's all in the [javadoc for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Yes i have done the same thing but somehow it messes with i18n feature

Comment: Moreover the return type of parse() is String so i need to again use format() method to convert the String back to Date which is why multiple language support will fail

Comment: @Abhiraj try to debug out the "Request Param".
I goss the date get with urlencode so the string of date look like this: 2017-05-12%2000%3A00%3A00 insted 2017-05-12 00:00:00

Comment: I cant particularly track Request Parameter as it is a POST request and also i tries to alert the Date it gives me expected format as YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: Take a look this article: https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-from-the-trenches-parsing-date-and-time-information-from-a-request-parameter/